# Распарсить Json с отсутствующим полем. AsyncTask.OnPostExecute

Tags: android, json

Есть url1 и url2 откуда скачиваю данные из интернета с помощью AsyncTask. Поля  Json схожие. Единственное, что их отличает- это отсутствие у url2 в json'е поля end_time. Оба url запускаю одним AsyncTaskом. Первый url выводит все в Recyclerview, а второй - нет. Попробовала поставить

```
if(jsonObject.getString("end_time")!=null)
```

а также

```
if(jsonObject.getString("end_time")!="")
```

все равно не работает.

Нужно создать два отдельных AsyncTask или есть другой выход?

Comment: Проверить перед `getString` на существование с помощью `has` или ловить исключение от `getString`, вообще смотрите документацию там все понятно: https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#getString(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

метод `json.optString(key, defaultValue)` вернет `defaultValue`, если не найдет `key`

Answer (score -1):

Попробуй

```
if(!jsonObject.getString("end_time").equals(null))
```

или

```
if(!jsonObject.getString("end_time").equals(""))
```

и не забудь про trim()